# Storing multiple arguments in a string with quotes in shell

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I need to include a header in my curl request to include `Authorization: Bearer 348129` header.

My script looks something like this:

```
authorization='-H "Authorization: Bearer ${JWT}"'
```

And later on in my shell script I use my variable like this:

```
somevar="$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" $authorization "$url")"
```

However this expands to:

```
 -H '"Authorization:' Bearer '${JWT}"'
```

on the terminal.

So the way I am declaring / quoting the somevar variable is faulty. Can someone help me declare somevar with proper quotes?

Comment: You can try also with backticks ` , although $(...) is recommended

Comment: If you want to store multiple words, the correct data structure for this is an array. This is covered in detail in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash, everything inside single quotes is [preserved verbatim](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html). Variables will not be interpolated.

Try the following:

```
authorization="Authorization: Bearer ${JWT}"
somevar="$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" -H "$authorization" "$url")"
```

Comment: Thanks! Would the same solution work if authorization="--cert "${ADMIN_CERT_PATH}" --key "${ADMIN_KEY_PATH}"" instead?

Comment: @JavaDeveloper It wouldn't be necessary to assign the flag and value to a variable, just include 
them in the call to `curl`.. like `$(curl --cert "${ADMIN_CERT_PATH}" "$url")` etc..

Comment: Nothing in this answer is *false*, but as of the present [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53716178/3), it fails to discuss *any* of the several approaches (array variables, shell functions, conditional multi-word expansions -- such as `${authorization+-H "$authorization}`) conventionally used to work around the limitation at hand.